# Present perfect simple past

Tags: tense, present-perfect, past-simple

[**Source**](http://cy.cyworld.com/home/30436415/post/4BAC50627515775AF9428401)

> "Libraries today are different from those in the 1800s. For example, the contents of libraries have changed greatly through the years."

I can't understand why it uses present perfect. I think with "Through the years" (in 1800s) it should use simple past.  Thank you in advance:)

Comment: it should be "througout the years"

Comment: They are both prep. So "through " is also right. Is it? Or not.. Plz excuse my poor English:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is not about changes which happened in the 19th century but about changes which occurred in the years since the 19th century, as a result of which we have very different libraries today.

This is the core use of the present perfect: to mention a past eventuality ("contents changed") as the source from which a present state ("libraries today") arose.

For more about this see [*What is the perfect, and how should I use it?*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/32), especially §§ [3.1 Grammatical meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13260/32), [3.2 Pragmatic meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13261/32) and [4. When and how should I use the perfect?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13262/32).

Comment: I got it roughly. But how could we know the answer without guessing  the meaning? I mean, Grammatically , using simple past is right or not?  Thank you so much

Comment: @Beth It's grammatical, but it's a different focus. When you use the simple past, you are focused on the past; when you use the present perfect you are talking about the past in order to describe the present.